# How to restrict user from putting in a char or negative input with exception handling?

Tags: java, exception

I'm trying to restrict the user from putting in a char or a negative number input the scanner. I want the code to loop back to asking the question until the user input 1 or bigger.

I've tried (InputMistmatchException e) and a few other exceptions but it does not work. I'm not sure if this is right but (Exception e) should catch most/all error?

```
int x = 1;
int size = 0;

do {
    try {
        System.out.println("How many random numbers between 1 and 100 would you like to generate?");
        size = input.nextInt();
        x=2;
    }   catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Wrong input");
    }
} while (x==1);
```

Comment: Why dont you use `if (size < 1) throw new InvalidParameterException("")` ?

Comment: `input.nextInt()` simply asks for the next integer. Negative values are perfectly valid integers. You need some kind of logic if you wish to restrict them (e.g. `if (size < 0) { continue; }`). Another way would be to wrap the call to `input.nextInt()` and throw an exception if the given value is negative, and then catch this exception in your main loop.

Comment: I agree, use of exception is rather unusual here.

Comment: What is the result you are getting when you run it?